# run-sonar-swift.sh with custom swiftlint .yml file

Tags: swift, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarlint, swiftlint

i have a problem with my .yml rules. I can include them into my project, he does get the custom rules, but I cannot show them in sonarqube, because he says he does not know the rules.
can anyone help me?
my .swiftlint.yml file is in the homedirectory and I only run the run-sonar-swift.sh with swiftlint, tailor and lizard.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

To have your .yml files analyzed, you need to install an analyzer that handles that language. I'm not currently aware of any such plugin.

Comment: Thanks, but local, the analyse is correct, but sonarqube cannot interpret the result. 
Running Tailor................................Running Lizard...Running SonarQube using SonarQube Runner.WARN: SCM provider autodetection failed. No SCM provider claims to support this project. Please use sonar.scm.provider to define SCM of your project.
WARN: The rule 'SwiftLint:curly_brackets' does not exist.
..WARN: Metric 'lines' is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Provided value is ignored.
So I get this error

Comment: It looks like there is no way to include custom rules to SonarQube at the moment!